# Change javascript Object attributes to nested object values

Tags: javascript, object, nested-object

so I have an object with the following format

```
const objA = {
              A: {a: 1, b: 2},
              B: {a: 3, b: 4},
             }
```

And I'm trying to to obtain a new object with the structure below

```
objB = {
      A: 1,
      B: 3,
    }
```

where the value of each key it's the value of the attribute `a` in the nested object. I´ve been having trouble using functional programming

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a loop?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to javascript and coding in general, I'll read the help center, thanks!
I've tried a loop and it worked... But I was just trying to accomplish the same result using functional programming to learn more and after a couple hours couldn't figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may traverse [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const objA = {A:{a:1,b:2},B:{a:3,b:4},},
             
      result = Object.keys(objA).reduce((r,key) => (r[key] = objA[key].a, r),{})
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You should just loop through the keys of the parent object, and assign the value of the inner object's key `a` to them. This is how,

```js
const objA = {
              A: {a: 1, b: 2},
              B: {a: 3, b: 4},
             }
const objB = {}

for (var key in objA) {
    if (objA.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         objB[key] = objA[key].a
    }
}
```

Output:

```js
objB = {
      A: 1,
      B: 3,
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought there was a way to accomplish this same thing by using some maybe reduce or deconstructing.